# Find value in Array in objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a NSArray structure likes this {w123,123,234,345,w124,234,235,w125,234,453,435,....}

What I am trying to do is to specify which one begins with "w" then do something 
But I don't know how to do that in objective C, anyone can help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

```
for (NSString *text in myArray) {
    if ([text hasPrefix:@"w"]) {
       // Do something.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use *NSPredicate*.

```
NSString *searchStr = @"w";  // or something else
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", searchStr];
NSArray *resultArray = [mainArray fileteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

The *resultArray* will contain all the strings that start with *searchStr(@"w", in this case)*.

**Case sensitivity:** Here *c* and *d* are used for *case* and *diacritic* insensitivity.

> String comparisons are by default case and diacritic sensitive. You can modify an operator using the key characters c and d within square braces to specify case and diacritic insensitivity respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Code as,

```
for(NSString * str in array)
{
 if([str hasPrefix:@"w"])
   //Do something
}
```

Comment: Dont use characterAtIndex method, if there is a string with length 0, the app will crash. So im editing my answer

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best option would be to iterate through the array and check if that string begins with "w".