# how to check if an object which start with *code* exist in an array for iphone

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

i have the following array:

```
(    
   "code=892498239847234792387",

   "ID=22",

   "status:true"   
)
```

in this i want to check whether there is an object which starts with string "code" and if there is then i want to retrieve the value of that.

Does any one can help me.....

Comment: where does this data come from?

Comment: Assuming you're using objective-c: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663792/find-value-in-array-in-objective-c

Comment: @Mark:i just gave an example array.

Comment: The reason is that it might be better to get the original data into something else e.g. a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSRegularExpression class for this. Or just use `rangeOfString:` method of NSString class. It will return range with `location` field `0` if this substring is at the beginning of your string